# Extraing data from json array and separate according to type

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I am currently trying to extract information from a json array using `json_decode($result,true)`. The background here is that there is another php script getting information from a database and it is sending the data to me as `json_encoded` result.

using `print_r($json)` i get the following

```
Array
(
[result] => 1
[message] => Query Successful
[data] => Query Output
[0] => Array
    (
        //Several values

        [test] => test
        [Example] => catcatcat
        [choice2] => B

    )
[1] => Array
     [test]=> test
//etc....
```

I understand we can use a simple for loop to get some stuff to display or in this case I used

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($json); $i++){
    echo $json[$i]['test'];
    //etc etc
}
```

and that will display the value. But what I cant figure out is how to send that to my HTML page as an output as a list.

I am trying to get it to display as following

1. Test catcatcat B
2. Test etc etc

--This may be a separate question but for me to learn I want to know if it's possible to actually break down the array and send to html as radio input and turn it into a value to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON result is a mixture of 1st level elements and sub-arrays, so you'll need to filter those.

Use a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) like this to output radio buttons:

```
foreach($json as $current) {
    if(!is_array($current))
        continue; // skip top level properties that aren't sub arrays

    echo '<input type="radio" name="yourradio" value="' . $current['choice2'] . '"> ' . $current['test'] . ' ' . $current['Example'];
}
```

The value of the radio button and the labels are up to you, but that's the general idea.